# Binance close coin-m futures position (dapi/v1)

Tags: node.js, binance, binance-api-client

I would like to close a position on Binance's COIN-M Delivery market, using node and "node-binance-api". However seems like there's no simple way to close a position. Could anyone help a binance API newbie like me?

If I create a take profit - buy order (because my position is a sell order), with closePosition=true (as it's stated here: https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/delivery/en/#new-order-trade) I'm either getting `Stop price less than zero.` or `Order would immediately trigger.`.

Does anyone know an easier solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I just found out that I can simply make a BUY MARKET order, and don't have to worry about any close position field. I also had to send the reduceOnly field, to make sure that no new BUY position will be created.